# while loop that can switch between two players?

Tags: bash

Can I use a while loop to switch between two players in a game?
I have this bash while loop but it is not working.
I used "U: for user and "C" for computer.

```
U=0; c=0;
while [[ c -eq 0 ]] && [[ u -eq 0 ]]
 echo who goes first c or u 
read -n 1 input 
if [[ input == c ]]
then 
  c=1
else 
   if [[ input == u ]]
   then 
      u=1
    else 
    echo your input is not valid
   fi
fi
done
```

Comment: Is the question as in the title (creating a loop that alternates between the players) or as in the question (the code seems to just determine who goes first)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

But first, the test should use the variable value, not the name. Instead of `while [[ c -eq 0 ]]` you should use:

```
while [[ "$c" -eq 0 ]]
```

that also apply to several later tests, like [[ input == c ]] should be:

```
if [[ "$input" == c ]]
```

Also, the variable declaration at the start should be (lowercase)

```
u=0; c=0;
```

Not `U=0; c=0;`.

And third, you are missing a `do` after the while:

```
u=0; c=0;
while [[ $c -eq 0 ]] && [[ $u -eq 0 ]]
do
    echo who goes first c or u 
    read -n 1 input 
    if [[ $input == c ]]
    then 
        c=1
    else 
        if [[ $input == u ]]
        then 
            u=1
        else 
            echo your input is not valid
        fi
    fi


done
echo "The var u is $u"
echo "The var c is $c"
```

That works.
But it should be easier with a case statement:

```
while
    echo "Who goes first c or u? : "
    read -n1 input
do
    echo
    case $input in
        c)  c=1; u=0; break;;
        u)  c=0; u=1; break;;
        *)  echo "your input is not valid";;
    esac
done
echo "The var u is $u"
echo "The var c is $c"
```

Or, since you are using plain bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -p "Who goes first c or u? : " -t10 -n1 input
do
    echo
    [[ $input == c ]] && { c=1; u=0; break; }
    [[ $input == u ]] && { c=0; u=1; break; }
    printf '%30s\n' "Your input is not valid"
done
echo "The var u is $u"
echo "The var c is $c"
```

Or maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
u=0; c=0
echo "Who goes first user or computer ? "
select input in user computer; do
    case $input in
        computer )  c=1; break;;
        user )      u=1; break;;
        *)          printf '%50s\n' "Your input \"$REPLY\" is not valid";;
    esac
done
echo "The var u is $u"
echo "The var c is $c"
echo "The selection was $input"
```

Or (sine the selection is in `input`) shorter:

```
echo "Who goes first ? "
select input in user computer; do
    [[ $input =~ user|computer ]] && break
    printf '%50s\n' "Your input \"$REPLY\" is not valid"
done
echo "The selection was $input"
```